# PDO prepare/execute the table and append WHERE's

Tags: php, pdo, append, execute

I'm trying to do the following:

```
public function checkResult($table, $appends)
{
    $append = null;
    foreach ($appends as $key => $val)
        $append = " AND `{$key}` = '{$val}'";

    $result = $this->fetchObj("
        SELECT  *
        FROM    :cms_table
        WHERE   id :append
    ", array(
        ":cms_table" => $table
        ":append" => $append
    ));

    return ($result ? true : false);
}
```

But I can't get this working because I don't know how to do this in PDO.
Also when I leave the `:append` my query isn't working either. It looks like I can't execute a table. When I change `:cms_table` to the `cms_pages` (table I need) it works correctly.

I couldn't find a thing about such query's in PDO. Anyone who can help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to outsmart yourself.

You don't need no `checkResult()` function, as well as no other function of similar structure.

```
$sql   = "SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE field = ? AND col = ?";
$found = $db->fetchObj($sql, array(1,2));
```

is all you actually need.